# Put background music in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use bacground music in Angular 6 project but i can't make it work.
I tried using Howler and nothing, here is what i did:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Howl, Howler} from 'howler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio',
  templateUrl: './audio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio.component.css']
})
export class AudioComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const sound = new Howl({
      src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3']
    });

    // Play the sound.
    sound.play();

    // Change global volume.
    Howler.volume(0.5);
  }

}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Doesn't work as in no errors, and no music?

Comment: do you have a `sound.webm` or a `sound.mp3` saved in your project? what if you replaced them with `src: ['http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-mp3', 'http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-aac']`?

Comment: yes this error: ERROR in src/app/audio/audio.component.ts(17,5): error TS2663: Cannot find name 'sound'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.sound'?
src/app/audio/audio.component.ts(23,5): error TS2663: Cannot find name 'sound'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.sound'?

Comment: Could be path issue if it can't find the sound file, but I see you can also fallback to html5 as well.

     var sound = new Howl({
      src: ['assets/path-to-audio/001.mp3'],
      html5 :true
    });

    sound.play();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at different examples on their site, what if you instantiate your sound variable outside of ngOnInit?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Howl, Howler} from 'howler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio',
  templateUrl: './audio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio.component.css']
})
export class AudioComponent implements OnInit {

  sound = new Howl({
     src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3']
  });

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Play the sound.
    this.sound.play();

    // Change global volume.
    Howler.volume(0.5);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! but it isn't working :( i don't get errors now..but the music doesn't play

Answer (score 5):

Could be path issue if it can't find the sound file, but I see you can also fallback to html5 as well.

```
var sound = new Howl({ src: ['assets/path-to-audio/001.mp3'], html5 :true }); 
sound.play()
```

also make sure you have the types installed?

```
npm install --save @types/howler
```

Comment: Thanks! but it isn't working :( i don't get errors now..but the music doesn't play

Comment: Yes i put the correct path, and i tried that too xD